# C array print segmentation fault?

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Why am I getting Segmentation fault? Could you give me some understadable explanation? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int i,j;

   char* ips[1000];
   char ip[15]  = "192.34.132.52";
   char port[4] = "4003";

   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      sprintf(ips[i], "%s:%d", ip, port);
   }

   for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      printf("[%d] = %s\n", j, ips[j]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is just so much wrong with this code... I wouldn't even know where to begin.

Comment: You are trying to modify a read-only constant, but who could tell until you use a debugger and see where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't allocate the memory for `ips[i]`, [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) doesn't do it for you. Add a line in the first `for` loop, before the `sprintf`:

```
ips[i] = malloc(sizeof(ip)+sizeof(port)+2);
```

**EDIT**: as huseyin tugrul buyukisik noted, `port` isn't big enough to hold 4 characters *and* a null terminator. And you should use the `%s` modifier for it as `port` is a string as well.

Comment: Also port[4] has 4 chars but no space for null to sign the end of it.

Comment: Well spotted, editing.

Comment: `%d` modifier for the port lol

Comment: :D char to int converter is needed.

Comment: 1000 dangling pointers and 10 are assigned into undefined behaviour. :D :D >:c

Comment: Oh cmon guys, just came from PHP to C after few years :D You could imagine its disaster! ^^

Comment: Unfortunately, the argument you're passing to `malloc()` is completely wrong. `ip` is an array of char, so `sizeof(ip[i])` is equivalent to `sizeof(char)`, which is guaranteed to be equal to `1`, `port` is also an array of char, so `sizeof(port[i])` will also be `1`, so what you're passing to `malloc()`, effectively, is `4`. In this particular case, it would be valid to `malloc( sizeof(ip) + sizeof(port) + 2)`, but I _would not_ recommend that in the general case.

Comment: ... _would not_ recommend that in the general case, because while in this particular case, `ip` and `port` are actual arrays, people working with strings tend to be using objects of type `char *`, and `sizeof(char *)` isn't going to give you the length of a string, it'll give you the size of the pointer (usually `4` or `8`).

Comment: True, edited the answer to be correct in this specific case.

Comment: I've edited your answer to change `NULL` to "null". `NULL` is a null *pointer* constant, not a null character.